# Preventing scapy from printing results

Tags: python, snmp, scapy

So I have a SNMP script in Scapy as below:

```
for i in range(j, k+1):
    ip = iprange + str(i)
    print 'Sending SNMP request to: ' +ip + "\n"
    p = IP(dst=ip)
    SNMP(community="public", PDU=SNMPget(id=1416992799, varbindlist=[SNMPvarbind(oid=ASN1_OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"))]))
    pkt = sr1(p, timeout=0.08)
```

And I get the desired result when I get a hit (an answer of 1):

```
Sending SNMP request to: 192.168.1.200

Begin emission:
.Finished to send 1 packets.

Received 1 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
Sending SNMP request to: 192.168.1.201

Begin emission:
.Finished to send 1 packets.

Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

However, I only really want Scapy to print out the results when an answer is 1, not when I don't have a hit (0). Is it possible to do this in Scapy?

Answer (score 0):

Line 205 in scapy/sendrecv.py reads

```
if verbose:
    print "\nReceived %i packets, got %i answers, remaining %i packets" % (nbrecv+len(ans), len(ans), notans)
```

So there is no option to only print this when ans > 0 (note that there is no way to shortcut this print in the context of the function). You can either change the source code to

```
if verbose and len(ans)>0:
    print "\nReceived %i packets, got %i answers, remaining %i packets" % (nbrecv+len(ans), len(ans), notans)
```

or much more preferable, just parse the output better.